# Recycleview displaying a grey area

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

the `RecyclerView` is not shown as in the picture below and i cannot find 
any solution.
What i tried:

- Rebuild
- Clean project
- Invalidate Cache

[image]

My build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.user.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

This is the activity_main.xml shown in the picutre

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will add the xml code shown in the picture, but i cannot add more code since i didnt write any other code.

Comment: What version of Android Studio you are using? If recyclerView dependency is already added and rebuild didn't help, that might be a bug which you can use older APIs dependencies like 27.1.1 or new versions of Android Studio like canary version.

Comment: On display side scroll down this design you will find errors and refresh options.

Comment: @Mohsen Thanks! Your post reminded me to upgrade Android to 3.2! Now it works, sometimes it can be so easy ...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `28.0.0` support library-APIs dependency actually works **better** with *Android Studio 3.2.0* and up and this is because of `AndroidX` migrating.

So, upgrading Android Studio will help since you already added `RecyclerView` dependency and there were no issues with the preview nor, no errors shown.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got rid of my gray recyclerview was pasting 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0' to dependencies. Sorry in case this is what you did to begin with!

There is another way to do it which is clicking on the little download icon that appears next to recyclerview when you search for it but that always results in the grey screen for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after spending approximately 2 days to figure it out, I went forward to

•delete the activity 
•create a new one 
•then add the RecyclerView to it and it worked like charm.

Comment: Consider formatting the bullets so that each of the points fall in a different line. Just add another blank line between them.